# What is the JPA entity type to be used if we use java 8 type ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, hibernate, zoneddatetime

I am migrating from joda to java 8 ,
initially i had this as my entity type :

```
import org.joda.DateTime;
 @Type (type=org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime)
 private DateTime  dateTime
```

I am migrating to ZonedDateTime now,

What should be my entity type ?

Should it be org.hibernate.type.ZonedDateTimeType?

searched a bit , could not find any satisfactory answers,

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generally, just include the Hibernate `java8` support package and don't worry about specifying it.'

Comment: i have 5.3.1.Final, believe that should cover

Comment: You still need the optional `java8` Hibernate package included, unless they rolled it in in the last 5.3 RCs (possible, but I hadn't seen that announcement).